# what is a path that cover all of $S^n$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Here is the meaning of "cover" which I can't understand:
Prove that if $n\ge 2$, then $S^n$ is simply connected. hint: Use Exercise 2.5 to
show that every loop in $S^n$ is homotopic to a loop that does not ***cover*** all of $S^n$.
Here is Exercise 2.5 which I can use it:
Show that any path in $S^n$ is homotopic with endpoints fixed to a polygonal path on $S^n$, where "polygonal" is now interpreted to mean that the path is formed from arcs lying on great circles of $S^n$.

Comment: It simply means that the image of the path is all of $S^n$.

Comment: @ZhenLin have you a sample of this path for $S^2$ please

Comment: It is any loop you can think of. It is more surprising that there *are* surjective loops $S^1\to S^2$.

Comment: @PeterFranek Do you mean all loops cover all of $S^2$?

Comment: No, I mean most loops do not, sorry for the confusion. There are, however, space-filling curves that do. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve See also the Hahn–Mazurkiewicz theorem.

Comment: However, a space-filling map $S^1\to S^n$ will fail to be continuous due to the compactness of $S^1$.

Comment: @Arthur ? $S^n$ is compact

Comment: @PeterFranek but a closed ball around some point in $S^n$ would contain the image of infinitely many closed intervals in $S^1$, which fails to be closed by compactness of $S^1$.

Comment: @Arthur I don't understand what you talk about. A closed neighborhood of a point in $S^n$ is compact,as well as all $S^n$. Moreove, anything that can be embedded as a bounded closed set to some $\mathbb{R}^m$ is compact. (And also many other spaces)

Comment: @PeterFranek I just checked it up, and it turns out I remembered incorrectly. It can be space-filling, but for any small ball, it can only enter and leave the ball a finite number of times, and therefore the homotopy that pushes each of these part segments to the boundary of the small ball is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context for a path or loop in a topological space $X$ to "cover" $X$ simply means that the continuous function $f : [0,1] \to X$ or $f : S^1 \to X$ which defines the path or loop is surjective: for each $y \in X$ there exists  $x \in \text{domain}(f)$ such that $f(x)=y$. This is quite different from other topological uses of the word "cover".

If $X$ is a manifold of dimension $\ge 2$ and if $f$ is smooth, or piecewise smooth (e.g. if $X$ is contained in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $f$ is polygonal) then $f$ is not surjective. But even for certain higher dimensional compact spaces like $X=S^n$ there do exist surjective continuous paths and loops, as is shown in [the link provided by @PeterFranek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve).